# PHP cURL cookie not saved after curl_close

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I couldn't access the cookie file after curl_close() although it's created successfully (not a file path issue). So, I added a 15 seconds of sleep after curl_close() and I noticed that the cookie file is created only after the 15 seconds, i.e. after the whole php file ends.

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        //I can't find the cookie file here
    
        sleep(15);
```

Comment: Yes, and the file is created successfully, and I can open it after the file execution finishes

Comment: Did you try to `unset($ch)` after the close?

Comment: @DarkBee Thank you, unset did the trick, please post it as an answer

Comment: @user973254 kinda answered the question already. Calling `unset` will trigger the destructor

Comment: @user973254 OK, update your answer with code example `unset($ch);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual entry for [`curl_close`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php):

> This function has no effect. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, this function was used to close the resource.

This reason is explained in [this article](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/resource-CurlHandle) :

> From PHP 8 and forward, curl_init function returns an instance of \CurlHandle class
>
> Because the handlers are now objects, the resources will be destroyed during garbage collection, unless the handler is explicitly closed with an unset() call.

To release the cookie file resource you need to [unset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the curl handle :

```php
unset($ch);
```